# Reordenar columnas de boostrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Necesito conseguir con bootstrap 4 rehubicar el div, para que no me deje un hueco. No se si me explico. Creo que con las imágenes queda mejor explicado lo que quiero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que con bootstrap 3, esto pasaba de forma automática y había que arreglar "el problema" con .clearfix, que dejaba el hueco, pero yo necesito lo contrario.

El código que tengo es simple:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row clearfix">
        <div style="border: 1px solid red;" class="col-12"><p  class="text-center">12</p></div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 150px;" class="col-6"> <p  class="text-center">6</p></div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 50px;" class="col-6"> <p  class="text-center">6</p></div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 50px" class="col-6 "> <p  class="text-center">6</p></div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 90px " class="col-6 "> <p  class="text-center">6</p></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

A ver si me pueden ayudar. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

## Quitar espacio superior

Puedes modificar la estructura para dividir en dos columnas el contenido, y sobre esas dos columnas crear rows y cols. Es decir utilizar las 2 columnas como contenedores:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 border">
                12
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 border">
                        6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam blandit elit sed tortor auctor, in accumsan dui efficitur. Aenean varius a ex at bibendum. 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 border">
                        6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam blandit elit sed tortor auctor, in accumsan dui efficitur. Aenean varius a ex at bibendum. 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 border">
                        6  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 border">
                        6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam blandit elit sed tortor auctor, in accumsan dui efficitur. Aenean varius a ex at bibendum. 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

## Misma Altura

Si quieres que las columnas izquierda y derecha tengan la misma altura  tienes varias opciones con sus pros y contras:

#### Definir altura fija

Puedes fijar una altura y poner un overflow scroll. Esto trae un problema pues no se va a adaptar a tu contenido y tendras un scroll si superas esa altura en alguna de las columnas

#### Usar Tabla

En lugar de utilizar los contenedores de Bootstrap puedes utilizar una tabla, las tablas siempre tienen los  del mismo tamaño dentro de una misma <tr>

#### Modificar la altura dinámicamente

Puedes utilizar JS para actualizar la altura (fija) de los contenedores Bootstrap una vez que se haya cargado el contenido

Answer (score 0):

Al tener todas los `.col` al mismo nivel, van a tratar siempre de adaptarse entre sí si tienen hueco suficiente para posicionarse. Si quieres evitar este comportamiento deberías envolverlos con filas, para determinar que columnas tienen que pertenecer a la misma fila.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.pequena {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-12">
  
  </div>
</div><div class="row">
  <div class="col col-6 grande">
  
  </div>
  <div class="col col-6 pequena">
  
  </div>
</div>
</div><div class="row">
  <div class="col col-6 pequena">
  
  </div>
  <div class="col col-6 grande">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Pero en mi caso real, no sé cuanto ocupara cada caja. Dado que se mostrará información de base de datos. Obviamente puedo poner un límite, pero si es seguro que las dos caja (izquierda y derecha) no tendrán el mismo tamaño y quiero tener que determinarlo

Comment: El tamaño de las cajas viene determinado por su contenido. He modificado el **CSS** para que siempre deje un hueco de 40px en la parte inferior de los cols con clase **pequeno** de esta manera conseguirías lo que quieres independientemente de la longitud del contenido de los cols. Esos 40px los puedes cambiar dependiendo del tamaño del "hueco vacio" que necesites. Si no necesitas hueco vacío de un tamaño determinado, sino que lo quieres es que si las columnas tienen una altura diferente se quede ese hueco, con quitar el margin-bottom que puse te valdría.